# Coffeescript and jQuery not working using Ruby on Rails on a particular view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I'm having a javascript issue with Ruby on Rails (4.1.4). It is only with one controller and I can't figure out why- does anyone have any idea? Thank you.

```
####This works :)
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $('#redemption_amount').keyup updateWorth
  $('#redemption_amount').change updateWorth

 updateWorth = ->
    discount = ($('#discount').val() / 100)
    worth = $(this).val() * discount
    $('#redemption_worth').html(worth.toFixed(2))
#####
```

Here is the issue:

```
####This does not work :(
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $('#purchase_amount').keyup updatePoints
  $('#purchase_amount').change updatePoints

  updatePoints = ->
        points = (Math.round($(this).val() * 0.92))
        $('#purchase_points').html(points)
####
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation defines the structure of your CoffeeScript code so if your indentation is off then your code is also off.

In the first case:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $('#redemption_amount').keyup updateWorth
  $('#redemption_amount').change updateWorth

 updateWorth = ->
    discount = ($('#discount').val() / 100)
    worth = $(this).val() * discount
    $('#redemption_worth').html(worth.toFixed(2))
```

the JavaScript looks like:

```
var updateWorth;
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $('#redemption_amount').keyup(updateWorth);
  $('#redemption_amount').change(updateWorth);
});
updateWorth = function() { ... };
```

so by the time `keyup` and `change` are called, `updateWorth`'s value is a function and everything works fine.

In the second case:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $('#purchase_amount').keyup updatePoints
  $('#purchase_amount').change updatePoints

  updatePoints = ->
        points = (Math.round($(this).val() * 0.92))
        $('#purchase_points').html(points)
```

the JavaScript ends up like:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  var updatePoints;
  $('#purchase_amount').keyup(updatePoints);
  $('#purchase_amount').change(updatePoints);

  updatePoints = function() { ... };
});
```

Your indentation puts `updatePoints` *inside* the callback. When `keyup` and `change` are called, `updatePoints`'s value is `undefined` because the `updatePoints = function() { ... }` part hasn't been reached yet.

---

Rules of thumb:

1. Define things (in the code's line order) before you use them.
2. Be very careful and consistent with your whitespace: if you're indenting two spaces in one place then indent two spaces **everywhere**.

You should be saying:

```
updateWorth = ->
  discount = $('#discount').val() / 100
  worth = $(@).val() * discount
  $('#redemption_worth').html(worth.toFixed(2))

$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $('#redemption_amount').keyup updateWorth
  $('#redemption_amount').change updateWorth
```

and:

```
updatePoints = ->
  points = (Math.round($(@).val() * 0.92))
  $('#purchase_points').html(points)

$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $('#purchase_amount').keyup updatePoints
  $('#purchase_amount').change updatePoints
```